# User of the Library providing implementations of multitons via lambda

Tags: kotlin

Coming from Java Background, I've studied [this](https://kotlin-code.com/design-patterns/creational-patterns/singleton-multiton-pattern/) and it's implementing multitons but I've a different case, it's the user of my library that is passing implementations at runtime.

There are two pieces of code here, one belongs to library (precompiled) and the other is the user of the library code. I can change both library and user code to accomplish the objective.

**1. Library Code** (PreCompiled)

```
interface IPrinter {
    fun print()
}

open class Printer: IPrinter {

    companion object {
        private var printers = mutableMapOf<String, IPrinter>()

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(key: String, lambda: (key: String) -> IPrinter): IPrinter {
            if (printers[key] == null) {
                printers[key] = lambda(key)
            }
            return printers[key]!!
        }
    }

    private constructor(key: String) { // can use init too here.
        // some initializers
    }

    override fun print() {
        print("default implementation")
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

**2. User of the Library Code** linked against jar file

```
// it has to extend PrinterHost to inherit methods, problem -> Printer()
class PrinterImplementation: Printer(), IPrinter {

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(key: String): IPrinter {
            return Printer.getInstance(key) { key -> PrinterImplementation() }
        }
    }

    override fun print() {
        println("Print page from printer")
    }

}

// Usage: PrinterImplementation.getInstance("myPrinter")
```

I think the problem with (2 User of the Library code) is that I'm instantiating Printer() from the base class, trying to wrap my head around this implementation where inheritance is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always need `key` to construct a `Printer`, it could look like

```
open class Printer protected constructor(key: String) : IPrinter {

    companion object {
        private var printers = mutableMapOf<String, IPrinter>()

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(key: String, lambda: (key: String) -> IPrinter): IPrinter {
            if (printers[key] == null) {
                printers[key] = lambda(key)
            }
            return printers[key]!!
        }
    }

    init { 
        // some initializers
    }

    override fun print() {
        print("default implementation")
    }

    // ... other methods
}

class PrinterImplementation(key: String): Printer(key), IPrinter {

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(key: String): IPrinter {
            // can also be written shorter: Printer.getInstance(key, ::PrinterImplementation)
            return Printer.getInstance(key) { key -> PrinterImplementation(key) }
        }
    }

    override fun print() {
        println("Print page from printer")
    }

}
```

Consider also using a [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) instead of a `MutableMap` with `@Synchronized`:

```
    companion object {
        private val printers = ConcurrentHashMap<String, IPrinter>()

        inline fun getInstance(key: String, lambda: (key: String) -> IPrinter): IPrinter =
            printers.getOrPut(key) { lambda(key) }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, It's giving me some compilation errors for `instanceMap.getOrPut(factory)`, can you please check

Comment: I think it's `printers.getOrPut(key) { lambda(key) }`, please advise.

Comment: also another question, when you say `inline fun getInstance` that means it saves from having to tag `@Synchronized`

Comment: 1. Oh yes, clearly too tired. 2. It's using a `ConcurrentMap` which lets you avoid `@Synchronized` (in this case), `inline` is just a slight but free performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful, can you please also explain what is `::PrinterImplementation` in the shorter rewrite?

Comment: It's a [constructor reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#constructor-references) (equivalent to `{ key -> PrinterImplementation(key) }`).